# incompatible with attribute android:id (attr) reference troubleshoot

Tags: android

I'm new with android studio software development, when I start building new software, this error happens.

> error: '0+id/nav_home' is incompatible with attribute android:id (attr) reference.
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: '0+id/nav_home' is incompatible with attribute android:id (attr) reference., sources=[C:\Users\Ray\AndroidStudioProjects\MyCatholic\app\src\main\res\menu\navigation_menu.xml:14], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

and this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
android:id="0+id/nav_post"
android:title="Add New Post"
    android:icon="@drawable/add_post"/>

<item
    android:id="0+id/nav_profile"
    android:title="My Profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"/>

<item
    android:id="0+id/nav_home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/home"/>

<item
android:id="0+id/nav_friends"
android:title="Friends"
    android:icon="@drawable/friends"/>

<item
    android:id="0+id/nav_find_friends"
    android:title="Find Friends"
    android:icon="@drawable/find_people"/>


<item
    android:id="0+id/nav_message"
    android:title="Message"
    android:icon="@drawable/messages"/>

<item
    android:id="0+id/nav_setting"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/settings"/>

<item
    android:id="0+id/nav_logout"
    android:title="Log Out"
    android:icon="@drawable/logout"/>


</menu>
```

am I missing something ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
android:id="0+id/your_id"
```

isn't valid syntax. It's:

```
android:id="@+id/your_id"
```

Replace all `0+id` with `@+id`.

Comment: @garish View IDs can have uppercase letters.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error of

> AAPT: error: 'about' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference.

My code was this ;

```
<item
                android:id="about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_about_black_24dp"
                android:title="About" />
```

A little bit different to initial questions' code, But I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52577962/11375743) answer (Above accepted answer) and changed my code by adding '@+id' as below ;

```
<item
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_about_black_24dp"
                android:title="About" />
```

Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact error, but different cause. In my case, I should have moved the string into a `strings.xml` file.

```
android:description: A string that describes the service to users. 
The label should be set as a reference to a string resource, 
so that it can be localized like other strings in the user interface.
```

[source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#desc)